# How can I automatically type the word 'Sjees' on each line before the rest of the text?

Tags: python, automation

I want to know how it is possible to automate writing with python. I have a file with some numbers. Like this:

```
1234
5467
6576
4567
5678
4563
6590
and so on
```

I want to add a word before each 4 numbers without a space between it. So it must look like this:

```
Sjees1234
Sjees5467
Sjees6576
Sjees4567
Sjees5678
Sjees4563
Sjees6590
```

Does anyone know how I can do this with python? The numbers are in a different .txt-file

Comment: Have you written any code for this?

Comment: No because I have no idea where to start

Comment: So go find out: 1) how to read from a file, line by line, 2) how to concatenate 2 strings, and 3) how to print the results and/or write them to disk again

Comment: Okay, I will try it. Thank you for your steps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you would have to get the values from the txt file and insert them into a string, then convert that string into an array this can be done like so:

```py
txtFile = open('myPath/myFile.txt', 'r')

txtStringValue = txtFile.read()

txtFile.close()

txtArray = txtStringValue.split()
```

`txtFile` is a variable containing the file itself.

`open()` is a method that opens a file and take in two arguments first the path to the file the second the mode.

`r` is for reading from a file.
`w` is for writing to a file.
`a` is for opening a file and appending text to it.

`txtStringValue` is a variable containing the string value of the `txtFile` variable.

`read()` is a method for getting the value of a file as a string.

`close()` is a method for closing an opened file.

`txtArray` is a variable containing an array of the `txtStringValue` variable.

`split()` is a method for splitting a string into an array and it can take one argument for what the separator of the values are. It defaults to spaces that's why it is not specified in this example.

**Example**:

```py
str = "Hello world!"
arr = str.split()
print(arr)
```

`output: ["Hello", "world!"]`

After that we now have the values of the text file in an array.
Now we can start to insert your custom text to the start of the values and print them out.

```py
for index in range(len(txtArray)):
    print("Sjees" + txtArray[index])
```

Here we use a `for` loop that makes a range the length of the array.

`range()` is a method that takes either one or two arguments if two are inputted it makes a range between the first argument and the last./
If one argument is inputted it will make a range from 0 to the argument amount.

`len()` is a method that gets the length of an array.

`print()` is a method that outputs it's arguments to the console.

*This is all written on my phone on a bus going home, so if something is wrong feel free to call it out.*

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I will try it and look if I understand it.

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this:

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
     for line in f:
         print "Sjees" + str(line) # in case that your line is int
```

and to your second question :

```
ith open("file.txt", "r") as f,open("file2.txt","w") as f2: #the "r" wasn't closed
     for line in f:
         f2.write("Sjees" + str(line)) # in case that your line is int
```

Comment: Do you know how I can make a .txt with the output?

Comment: I've updated my answer, good luck :)

Comment: When I run this code, I get an error by the word 'with' 'f2'

Comment: It should work now ... There was a typo :)

Comment: :) it does work completely now

Comment: Btw you need another bracket at the last line